# How to: Use DisplayManager to get displays and set a bool

Tags: java, android

My understanding of Java is basically nonexistent .. I only really understand Dart.

However, I need to use `DisplayManager` and `getDisplays()` in order to set a boolean.

I need something like this (I know this isn't really java, it's just so someone can get an understanding):

```
DisplayManager displayManager = DisplayManager();
List<Display> displays = [];
bool hasDisplays = false;

void _getDisplays(){
displays = DisplayManager.getDisplays();
}

void _displayBool(){
if(displays.length > 1){
hasDisplays = true;
} else {
hasDisplays = false;
}
```

if someone could show me how the hell I'm supposed to do something like that, inside of this, it would be amazing

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know if there are physical displays connected?

Comment: Essentially I want to detect screen mirroring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `DisplayManager` with the `context.getSystemService()` function. Then you get the list of Displays (`Display[]`) from the `displayManager.getDisplays()` function. Then if you want to know if there are one or more displays in the list, set the statement to the boolean.

```
   DisplayManager displayManager = (DisplayManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
   Display[] displays = displayManager.getDisplays();
   boolean hasDisplays = displays.length >= 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this code:

```
class TestScreenCount {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] allScreens = env.getScreenDevices();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allScreens));
  }
}
```

This will output the connected displays, for my case (I have an external screen and a laptop screen):

```
[X11GraphicsDevice[screen=0], X11GraphicsDevice[screen=1]]
```